# Running exec within a grails web-app

Tags: linux, tomcat, grails, groovy, ffmpeg

I'm trying to call exec() on a grails server (tomcat6) to run ffmpeg conversions on demand for users.  My attempt is listed below:

```
def command = """ffmpeg -r 5 -i ./grails-app/assets/images/frame/%03d.jpeg -vcodec libvpx -r 5 out.webm"""
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()
def res = []
res << "return code: ${proc.exitValue()}"
res << "stderr: ${proc.err.text}"
res << "stdout: ${proc.in.text}"
return res
```

Running "ls -R".execute()  confirms the folder path as `./grails-app/pathname..`,
however any exec calls to the folder return "no such file or directory."
I have tried using the 
`appname/assets//frame/path` 
as well, but that did not help either.

The exact error is:
 
`Could find no file with path 'grails-app/assets/images/frame/%03d.jpeg' and index in the range 0-4 grails-app/assets/images/frame/%03d.jpeg: No such file or directory`

What am I doing wrong? How can I get execute to recognize the folder structure of the server?

Comment: You probably should make the path configurable. If 'assets' is the the assets pipeline plugin folder it will be at a different location in production. Create a war and take a look inside.

Comment: Or try to use something like this `assetPath(src: "images/frame/%03d.jpeg")`

Comment: Also maybe Grails do not like `%03d` in filenames it looks like String formatter. Please try to rename file.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by using %d instead of %03d (my files were named 1.jpg, 2.jpg and not 001.jpg etc.)  Thanks for the help everyone.